# Atomic increment of a counter in django

Tags: python, django, transactions, race-condition

I'm trying to atomically increment a simple counter in Django. My code looks like this:

```
from models import Counter
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_success
def increment_counter(name):
    counter = Counter.objects.get_or_create(name = name)[0]
    counter.count += 1
    counter.save()
```

If I understand Django correctly, this should wrap the function in a transaction and make the increment atomic. But it doesn't work and there is a race condition in the counter update. How can this code be made thread-safe?

Comment: To me it looks like such a waste not to use `+=` to avoid race conditions. Python users should already know there is a difference between `a += b` and `a = a + b`, so why not use that? Maybe it'll conflict with some cache data? Not sure.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use [an F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```py
from django.db.models import F
```

either in `update()`:

```py
Counter.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
Counter.objects.filter(name=name).update(count=F("count") + 1)
```

or on the object instance:

```py
counter, _ = Counter.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
counter.count = F("count") + 1
counter.save(update_fields=["count"])
```

*Remember to specify `update_fields`, or you might encounter race conditions on other fields of the model.*

A note on the [race condition avoided by using F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f) has been added to the official documentation.

Comment: should this be wrapped in a commit_on_success method?

Comment: One issue with this is if you need the updated value afterwards, you need to fetch it from the database. In certain cases, like ID generation, this can cause race conditions. For instance, two threads might increment an ID atomically (say from 1 to 3), but then both query for the current value and get 3, try to insert, explosion... Just something to think about.

Comment: In the second version, why not use the defaults kwarg to get_or_create, and then put the F object inside a `if created` block? Should be faster in the case of creation, right? I went ahead and put an answer demoing what I mean.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. Check the [django doc about F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F): _Another benefit of using F() is that having the database - rather than Python - update a field’s value avoids a race condition._

Comment: `get_or_create` returns a pair, so it should be `counter, created = ...` like in mlissner's answer.

Comment: @Bialecki you could just write `new_count = counter.count + 1` before doing the update.

Comment: So, basically after updating a field like that,model will hold an instance of django.db.models.expressions.CombinedExpression, instead of the actual result. If you want to access the result immediately: "counter.refresh_from_db()"

Comment: Every once in a while this fails for me and I end up with a smaller count than expected. Does every database backend support this? More specifically, does sqlite3 support this?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to increment a field value, but on the page I don't want to need to refresh it, to get the new value when I click the increment button.

Answer (score 20):

If you don't need to know the value of the counter when you set it, the top answer is definitely your best bet:

```
counter, _ = Counter.objects.get_or_create(name = name)
counter.count = F('count') + 1
counter.save()
```

This tells your database to add 1 to the value of `count`, which it can do perfectly well without blocking other operations.  The drawback is that you have no way of knowing what `count` you just set.  If two threads simultaneously hit this function, they would both see the same value, and would both tell the db to add 1.  The db would end up adding 2 as expected, but you won't know which one went first.

If you do care about the count right now, you can use the `select_for_update` option referenced by Emil Stenstrom.  Here's what that looks like:

```
from models import Counter
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def increment_counter(name):
    counter = (Counter.objects
               .select_for_update()
               .get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    counter.count += 1
    counter.save()
```

This reads the current value and locks matching rows until the end of the transaction.  Now only one worker can read at a time.  See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update) for more on select_for_update.

Comment: This answer has the best explanation. It wasn't till reading this one that I was convinced that `count = F('count') + 1` would work

Answer (score 18):

In Django 1.4 there is [support for SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#select-for-update-support) clauses, using database locks to make sure no data is accesses concurrently by mistake.

Comment: This was the solution I ended up going with combined with wrapping the block in the transaction.commit_on_success.

Comment: Exactly. The real problem is the race of the same data by different clients. An internal lock can make sure each client gets its own serial for its transaction.

Answer (score 9):

Keeping it simple and building on @Oduvan's answer:

```
counter, created = Counter.objects.get_or_create(name = name, 
                                                 defaults={'count':1})
if not created:
    counter.count = F('count') +1
    counter.save()
```

The advantage here is that if the object was created in the first statement, you don't have to do any further updates.

Answer (score 7):

Django 1.7

```
from django.db.models import F

counter, created = Counter.objects.get_or_create(name = name)
counter.count = F('count') +1
counter.save()
```

Answer (score -2):

Or if you just want a counter and not a persistent object you can use itertools counter which is implemented in C. The GIL will provide the safety needed.

--Sai

Comment: The asker was specifically asking for how to atomically increment a field in the database.

Comment: In this guy's defence, that isn't stated explicitly. Clearly intended though.