# Is this a safe way to increment and get the value of a counter in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using MySQL with the InnoDB engine and REPEATABLE-READ isolation level.

I have written a function which I think should atomically increment an IntegerField, and give me the value after the increment.  I would like opinions on whether my code is robust against concurrency issues.

My code looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  version = models.IntegerField()

  @staticmethod
  @transaction.commit_on_success
  def acquire_version(pk):
    MyModel.objects.filter(pk = pk).update(version = F('version') + 1)
    return MyModel.objects.get(pk = pk).version
```

My thinking is that in two concurrent calls, the UPDATEs will mutually exclude one another because of a write lock, and then REPEATABLE-READ should guarantee that my subsequent .get will give me the value after the UPDATE.  Am I right?

(This is not a general "how do I do an atomic increment?" question, there's already one of those.  This is about whether this one particular way is valid.)

Comment: Have you looked at http://stdbrouw.github.com/django-locking/ - I'm assuming you're doing this for optimistic locking

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598932/atomic-increment-of-a-counter-in-django

Answer (score 1):

A general rule-of-thumb is that [any sort of custom queries or customized query behavior should go into manager methods.](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/feb/25/managers/)
This makes sense in your case, because you can increment, save and return the version number at a very low level: during the actual query.

Thus, use a manager (`object = MyManager()`) and write a SQL query that increments the version number (`UPDATE mytable SET version=(version+1) WHERE pk=pk`, see [here](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlupdate.php)), and immediately return the incremented version of the model instance, before any other call can be executed.

See also [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/)

Comment: Okay, but is the code given in the question correct or faulty?

Comment: I think it is more dangerous because the actual implementation of .update() can be Django-version independent. Also you are doing a double and probably even a three-double lookup. Honestly I don't know if it is (presently) correct.