# How to get the count of most viewed product?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hi actually i new to django Restframe work. 
Here i have mentioned my model My question is that ? I don't know how to store the count of each product. and most viewed product should display in frontend.

**MODEL.PY**

```
class Products(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   image = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
   categories =  models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=Category,
       model_form_class=CategoryForm
   )
   specifications =  models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=Specifications,
       model_form_class=SpecificationsForm
   )
   description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   reviews =  models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=Reviews,
       model_form_class=ReviewsForm
   )
   drizzly = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   count = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: inside your view you could call a function which adds 1 to your `count` modelfield each time a user calls the view. But the problem would be that if a user clicks multiple times on a product it would count each click. So to do this properly you would need to save the users ID /IP adress and only add one if the user never viewed the product...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of doing that is to use **[atomic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598932/atomic-increment-of-a-counter-in-django?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)**:

```
from django.db.models import F

Products.objects.filter(name = name).update(count = F('count')+1)
```

**Note**: You have to have a `name` field set to `unique` or filter by another `unique` field.

Comment: My doubt is that. By clicking that product that count (values)should store in Count column(Product Model) –

Comment: Didn't get what do you mean?

Comment: Actually i want to display Most viewed products . For that i have added column called Count it should store the value that how many times Product has been clicked. And i want to display Most viewed Product.

Comment: `Products.objects.all().order_by('-count')[:100]`

Comment: For this I have kept separate column Count. So i want to store in that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170285/discussion-between-sudharsan-venkatraj-and-chiefir).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class based views, you can do something like:

```
Class ProductsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Products

    def get(self, **kwargs):
        self.object.count += 1
        self.object.save()
        return super(ProductsDetailView, self).get(**kwargs)
```

To order by count, within your model include

```
Class Meta:
    ordering = ['count']
```

Comment: My doubt is that. By clicking that product that count should store in Count column(Product Model)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Class ProductsDetailView(DetailView):
model = Products

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):       
    object = self.get_object()
    object.count = int(object.count) + 1
    object.save()
    return super(ProductsDetailView, self).get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```