# Django-How to do the visit counts?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

there is a question that makes me feel annoyed,what i want to do is when i request the detail.html then the views of Post model will add 1 as the visit counts ,how to do it?thanks.

blog/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
   views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

blog/views.py

```
def detail(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html')
```

Comment: Load the model, increment the count, and save it.

Comment: How to load ?what is the code ?thanks?

Comment: Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425711/how-to-add-a-page-view-count-for-django-detail-view/64274702#64274702), read more answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could increment the views count this way:

```
def detail(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    post.views += 1
    post.save()
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context={'post': post})
```

I assumed that since it is a detail view, you would receive an unique key to identify which post will be rendered (that can be done on `urls.py`)

Comment: post.views +=1 has race condition problem .. you should use `djanfo.models.F`