# Styling HTML for model property with verbose name in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django model like this:

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
    value = IntegerField()

    def custom_field(self):
        return self.value + 1
```

Then in my admin.py file, I have a model:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('id', 'custom_field')

     def custom_field(self, obj):

        if obj.total_counter_actual != obj.total_counter:
            color = 'red'
            return format_html(
                '<b style="color:{};">{}</b>',
                color,
                obj.custom_field
            )
        else:
            return obj.custom_field
    custom_field.short_description='My custom column name'
```

Although column name (implying analogue of verbose name) and styling both work as exepcted, instead of values I see something like `<bound method MyModel.custom_field of <MyModel: TEST_VALUE>>`. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `@property` decorator

checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58559066/13168118)
and the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods)