# How to Update field of Django model based on another model with foreign key relation

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models Betslip and Bet,I want to update value of Betslip.settled_status to 'Lost', if Bet.settlement_status is 'half_lost' or 'lost', can anyone create a method for it ?

````
class Betslip(models.Model):
    SETTLED_STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('InGame','InGame'),
        ('Won','Won'),
        ('Lost','Lost'),
        ('Refunded','Refunded')
    )
    settled_status = models.CharField(choices=SETTLED_STATUS_CHOICE,max_length=30)


class Bet(models.Model):
    SETTLEMENT_STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('','select'),
        ('won','won'),
        ('lost','lost'),
        ('refund','Refund'),
        ('half_won','half_won'),
        ('half_lost','half_lost'),
    )

  
    settlement_status = models.CharField(choices=SETTLEMENT_STATUS_CHOICE,max_length=30,)
    betslip = models.ForeignKey(Betslip,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='bet')```
````

Comment: What have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: try to read `django signals`

Comment: I tried override the save method, but couldn't find out the correct logic to save my value in betslip.settlement_status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can understand about @property from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558989/what-does-djangos-property-do)
and for using the bets object for getting bets' settlement status property you may use "reverse related object lookup" aka _set inside the Betlip property(since you have used foreign key for Betslip in Bet)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

In **Bet** model try this:

```
def update_settled_status(self):
    if self.settlement_status in ['lost','half_won']:
        self.betslip.settled_status = 'Lost'
        self.betslip.save()
```

Comment: I am not getting any error but it is also not changing value of betslip.settled_status, i ran migrations too..

Comment: I don't know exactly where you wanna use this. you can call this method like this: bet = Bet.objects.get(pk=_a_bet_pk)      bet.update_settled_status()          it will save the value with 'self.betslip.save()' in the method declaration.

Comment: I need to override the save method of **Betslip** to save new value in database, how can i call this function in save of Betslip?

Comment: You can do this in **Betslip** save method:    `self.bet.first().update_settled_status()`