# unable to substract two timefeild in django

Tags: django, django-models

Hi Team i have models as below. And i am trying to substract out time and in time .

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
   employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                default=1, related_name='Attendance')
    attendance_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    in_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    out_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    totaltime = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee) + '-' + str(self.attendance_date)

    @property
    def totaltime(self):
        FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
        currentDate = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        sub = datetime.strptime('out_time', FMT) -
            datetime.strptime('in_time', FMT)
        return sub
```

Still getting and error: ValueError: time data 'out_time' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Please advise what should i do ,I am expecting how i will substract two timefeild

Answer (score 0):

```
@property
def totaltime(self):
    total_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=self.out_time.hour, minutes=self.out_time.minute,
                                    seconds=self.out_time.second) - datetime.timedelta(hours=self.in_time.hour,
                                                                                      minutes=self.in_time.minute,
                                                                                      seconds=self.in_time.second)
    return total_time
```

Comment: Again error comes : TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.time

Comment: i did this  in_time = datetime.strptime(str(self.in_time), FMT)
              out_time = datetime.strptime(str(self.out_time), FMT) still error comes : alueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Comment: can you try now, I edited my answer. Your in_time and out_time was already TimeField

Comment: i tried but Exception Value: 
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta' /.

Comment: unable to sort the issue

Answer (score 0):

So, first, you are using `total_time` as a [@property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58559066/7100120), so you can just drop the field. Second, you need to use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to calculate the difference between times, which is where another problem arises, because it seems only to operate with `datetime` objects, so you must [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656394/7100120) that:

models.py:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                default=1, related_name='Attendance')
    attendance_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    in_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    out_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee) + '-' + str(self.attendance_date)

    @property
    def total_time(self):
        total = ( datetime.combine(date.today(), self.out_time) - 
                  timedelta(
                        hours=self.in_time.hour, 
                        minutes=self.in_time.minute, 
                        seconds=self.in_time.second
                    ) 
                )
        return total.time()
```

tests.py

```
class AttendanceTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.target_hour = 1
        self.target_minutes = 42
        self.target_seconds = 36

        now = datetime.now()
        in_time = time(now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
        dt = (datetime.combine(date.today(), in_time) + 
                timedelta(
                    hours=self.target_hour, 
                    minutes=self.target_minutes, 
                    seconds=self.target_seconds
                )
            )
        out_time = dt.time()
        
        self.employee = Employee.objects.create(
            username='employee',
            password='super_secret',
            email='employee@example.com'
        )

        self.attendance = Attendance.objects.create(
            employee=self.employee,
            attendance_date=date.today(),
            in_time=in_time,
            out_time=out_time
        )
        
    def test_attendance_total_time(self):
        total_time = self.attendance.total_time
        self.assertEqual(total_time.hour, self.target_hour)
        self.assertEqual(total_time.minute, self.target_minutes)
        self.assertEqual(total_time.second, self.target_seconds)
        print(total_time)
```

Comment: hi sir thanks for the ans it do not given any error but still it is returning none to me

Comment: I have updated the answer with a test, it does work well.